# How to open an external application from within my vscode extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, child-process

If I compile & run the below typescript code the application named Notion will open.

```
const cmd = 'open -a "/Applications/Notion.app"';
exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {});
```

If I run the same code inside my `extension.ts` file, the command will be executed but Notion will not be opened (nothing happens, also the `open` command produces no stdout, stderr or error). The same is true for other applications.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import {exec} from 'child_process'

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('helloworld.helloWorld', () => {
        const cmd = 'open -a "/Applications/Notion.app"';
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Running command: ${cmd}`);
        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {});
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

How to open an external application from within my vscode extension?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some environment variable(s) that are set for subprocesses which are spawned during extension execution prevent applications from opening. Cleansing the environment of the subprocess from all environment variables allowed me to open external applications from within my extension.

```
const options = {env: {}};
exec(cmd, options, (error, stdout, stderr) => {});
```